# raspberry pi 3 diskless (sdcard less) network boot

Tags: networking, pi-3, boot, boot-issues

***Looking for a full example that shows how to network boot (and keep running with whatever is baked into the ramdisk image) without any kind of SDcard in the PI.***

What I've done up until this point.

Followed the instructions here: [Link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes) and got my raspberry pi v3 to network boot and use an NFS share as a root file system.

Now, I am looking at network booting and using a ramdisk rootfs.
I have build a minimal initrd image w/ busybox and copied the compressed image into /tftpboot.

```
ls -la /tftpboot/initrd-3b.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 1087650 Feb  7 00:22 /tftpboot/initrd-3b.img
```

1087650 => 1098A2

I have tried just about every possible combination or the initrd params in config.txt and cmdline.txt.

**Setup 1**

```
/tftpboot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 rw ip=dhcp rootwait elevator=deadline loglevel=6 initrd=0x01f00000

/tftpboot/config.txt
initramfs initrd-3b.img 0x01f00000
```

**Outcome 1**
I see the DHCP traffic + Pi get the correct IP

- I see both the kernel and the initrd being tftpd to the Pi.
  At around 5 seconds in, it crashes with a Kernel Panic (secondary_start_kernel) from [<0010196c>] (0x10196c)

**Setup 2**

```
/tftpboot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 rw ip=dhcp rootwait elevator=deadline loglevel=6 initrd=0x01f00000,0x1098a2

/tftpboot/config.txt
initramfs initrd-3b.img 0x01f00000
```

**Outcome 2**
Same, at around 5 seconds in, it crashes with a Kernel Panic (secondary_start_kernel) from [<0010196c>] (0x10196c)

Also attempted to do:

```
initramfs initrd-3b.img followkernel
```

but this also does not work.

Comment: You've been around StackExchange for some time. I'm confused, as you should already know "I'm looking for a tutorial"-questions are discouraged.

Comment: @techraf I'm with you here but this does to be a very simple use case and I was expecting this to be documented / explained. I cannot believe I'm the only person that is trying to do this and believe that a pointer to the said example would help immensely.

Comment: Here is an example of such an example I've put together at some point in time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392655/how-to-consume-amazon-swf/28843218#28843218 It still receives a lot of traffic and has helped a lot of people. I believe helping someone after he/she explained the problem is more in the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this for future generation of explorers.

2 issues:

- the size was incorrect
- the init script used was exiting (finishing)

Both of them made the boot process go horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is likely to adapt a "live boot" disto. My Nard SDK being one example. It always run from a ramdisk, even when SD card is present. The development version in Git will have best chances for network boot to work.
http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/

Comment: thanks. will give this a shot. Still trying to understand how the network boot process works under the hood - but don't see any harm in using something prebuilt if the understanding is there.